# transpose from wide format to long format using a linux command

Tags: python, linux, awk, transpose

I was hoping to transpose a file from wide to long format preferably using a linux statement or a python statement.
My input data would look something like this:

```
   head1 M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7
   abcd A B C D E F G
   efgh A B C D E F G
   ijkl A B C D E F G
```

and would like the output to be like this:

```
   abcd A
   abcd B
   abcd C
   abcd E
   abcd F
   abcd G
   efgh A
   efgh B
   efgh C
   ...
```

Is it possible to do this, I have come across R code but would prefer to avoid using it as the files are quite large?

Thank you

Comment: *"Is it possible to do this"* Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i}' file
head1 M1
head1 M2
head1 M3
head1 M4
head1 M5
head1 M6
head1 M7
abcd A
abcd B
abcd C
abcd D
abcd E
abcd F
abcd G
efgh A
efgh B
...
```

If you want to skip the header

```
$ awk 'NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i}' file
```